# gcc can't optimize tail recursion of a std::vector<int>, exit with code 139?

Tags: c++, gcc, segmentation-fault, tail-recursion

I have this program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int foo(std::vector<int> bar) {
    if (bar[0] == 0)
        return bar[0];
    else 
    {
        bar[0] -= 1;
        return foo(bar);
    }
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> bar {9999999};
    std::cout << foo(bar);
}
```

Compile with `x86-64 gcc 12.2` using the flag `-O3` ([here](https://godbolt.org/z/d71ceY3a5)), it exit with code 139:

> Program returned: 139

which means my program has a segmentation fault.

So is my program undefined behaviour, or that `gcc` fails to optimize my tail recursion?

Comment: Tail recursion optimizations is not a requirement of C++, but some compilers can do it in limited circumstances. Apparently GCC doesn't do it in this case. You really have to look at the generated assembly code to see it (which is very easy to do on the compiler explorer). And I recommend you read through the GCC documentation and find out in which cases (if any) it will be able to do tail-recursion optimizations.

Comment: `int foo(std::vector<int> bar)` -> `int foo(std::vector<int> &bar)`

Comment: It's not a tail call since the argument must be destroyed after the recursive call has returned (unless the compiler can prove that it's not necessary). It's very easy to write functions that look tail-recursive but aren't in C++.